# How can you create two triangles next to an image?

Tags: html, css

How can you create two triangles next to an image?

As you can see in the jsfiddle, the triangles are not tounching the image. I want them to touch the image and the blue bar above.
I tried this post: [How can I have an image float next to a centered div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469801/how-can-i-have-an-image-float-next-to-a-centered-div) didn't work.

```css
.content {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.producten {
 margin-top: 4%;
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul.producten li {
 width: 315px;
}

ul.producten li img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 295px;
}

.producten_top {
 width: 315px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #3bcdff;
}

.producten_top h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.arrow_left {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid #1c1c1d;
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 float: left;
}

.arrow_right {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #1c1c1d;
 transform: rotate(315deg);
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="producten">
   <li>
    <div class="producten_top"><h1>Test</h1></div>
    <div class="arrow_left"></div>
    <img src="http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/144/images/hero_small/Giant_Panda_Hero_image_(c)_Michel_Gunther_WWF_Canon.jpg?1345515244" alt="Plafond lampen">
    <div class="arrow_right"></div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8yzdfrh/)**

what it needs to be:

[image]

Comment: `display: inline-block` is touch for this kind of layouting, since the elements are in the text flow, and even whitespace in your HTML code can mess things up. The space left and right to the triangles is caused by such spaces while the space above it is causes by the vertical spacing between lines of text (just as in normal text). You can eliminate this partially, but usually one would choose `position: absolute` to do this kind of positioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` instead of `display: inline-block` and give `8px` border for triangles instead of `5px` and set `display: block` and `margin: auto` for make `img` center. of course you need to set `position: relative;` for parent `(ul.producten li)`.

```css
.content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul.producten {
    margin-top: 4%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.producten li {
    width: 315px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.producten li img {
    display: block;
    width: 295px;
    margin: auto;
}

.producten_top {
    width: 315px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #3bcdff;
}

.producten_top h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.arrow_left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #1c1c1d;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 39px;
}

.arrow_right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #1c1c1d;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <ul class="producten">
        <li>
            <div class="producten_top"><h1>Test</h1></div>
            <div class="arrow_left"></div>
            <div class="arrow_right"></div>
            <img src="http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/144/images/hero_small/Giant_Panda_Hero_image_(c)_Michel_Gunther_WWF_Canon.jpg?1345515244" alt="Plafond lampen">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And what magic you did to get the solution?? please add explanation to your answer so OP can get the idea so next time he will try to do rather then copy and paste.. Thanx

Comment: Mmm..small white line bisecting your triangles in my browser (Firefox)

Comment: @James yes I see now.. but I think it's FF issue to rendering css triangle shape with borders.

Comment: @Leothelion Updated. Thanks for the tip, but thought when OP see the code will find out what's happened.

Comment: @James, that triangle border issue is common in ff with transform.. trying to solve from morning..

Comment: @Leothelion please read that comment under the question. try yourself with `display: inline-block` if you get good result so give an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

This technique makes a square div with a linear gradient alpha background that resembles a triangle.  As a bonus, by adjusting the distance between alpha=1 and alpha=0 (the percentages) in the gradients you can change the anti-aliasing of the diagonal line (the left arrow has more anti-aliasing in this example).

```css
.content {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.producten {
 margin-top: 4%;
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul.producten li {
    width: 315px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.producten li img {
    display: block;
    width: 295px;
    margin: auto;
}

.producten_top {
 width: 315px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #3bcdff;
}

.producten_top h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.arrow_left {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(28,28,29,1) 44%,rgba(28,28,29,0) 56%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
}

.arrow_right {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(28,28,29,1) 48%,rgba(28,28,29,0) 50%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="producten">
   <li>
    <div class="producten_top"><h1>Test</h1></div>
    <div class="arrow_left"></div>
        <div class="arrow_right"></div>
    <img src="http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/144/images/hero_small/Giant_Panda_Hero_image_(c)_Michel_Gunther_WWF_Canon.jpg?1345515244" alt="Plafond lampen">
    
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your css. The changes I made are:

- Set the same width for the blue header and image
- Set position fixed for image and right arrow
- Set the arrows degrees values in negative

Check it out...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>


 .content {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    ul.producten {
        margin-top: 4%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.producten li {
        width: 315px;
    }

    ul.producten li img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 315px;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .producten_top {
        width: 315px;
        height: 40px;
        background: #3bcdff;
    }

    .producten_top h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    .arrow_left {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 5px solid #1c1c1d;
        transform: rotate(-225deg);
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .arrow_right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #1c1c1d;
        transform: rotate(-315deg);
        float: right;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```